# noobie Git issue

Tags: git, git-clone

Having git installed, I am using it with another developer. 
I am not sure how to use git, but for some reason it keeps telling me that the folder I am interested in is already in sync after I do '`git sync`'. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and the git thing is not very clear to me. 
I would like to erase all the subfolders (all full with red marks and green marks) and simply clone the project so that it is in sync with what's on the web.
How can I do that?
(Using bitbucket.org)

Comment: The documentation on the git site is really good: http://git-scm.com/book.

Comment: Good god, all my windows-library folders are assigned with blue question marks!

Comment: also note that "sync" is not a git subcommand

Comment: Hint: give us a clue as to what your problem is in the subject. We don't care how new you are, we care what you're struggling with.

Comment: Well, I did as @Javi Camero said and went ahead and basically reinitialized the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to do. If you have already cloned the repository there is no need to sync it (In fact usually you never have to do that).
I recommend you to read [Git Reference](http://gitref.org/), it is a short guide where you will learn the basics about git and how to use it every day.